# simple javascript works in console but not greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm just trying to submit the already-filled-out login form at this site:
http://portal.mypearson.com/mypearson-login.jsp

In firefox console, I can type this:
doSubmit();
and it works fine but it doesn't work in greasemonkey. By 'doesn't work' I mean nothing happens. I can do document.forms[0].submit() but the page comes back complaining that the user and pass variables aren't set correctly.

What do I need to do to get the script that works in console to work in greasemonkey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried taking the functionality from the doSubmit() function and performing those actions?

A quick inspection of the code looks like this:

```
if (!validate(displayForm)) {return false;}
loginForm.loginname.value = displayForm.loginname.value;
loginForm.password.value = hex_md5(displayForm.password.value.toLowerCase());
loginForm.encPassword.value = 'Y';
loginForm.submit();
return true;
```

It looks like the form is actually just copying its values to another form and then submitting the other form.

You could first start by removing the onsubmit event by using:

```
displayForm.setAttribute("onsubmit", null)
```

Or you could just bypass the display form all together and go straight to the source. Your greasemonkey script would look something like this without all the extra steps:

```
// Setup your authentication values here
var username = "(Your user name)";
var password = "(Your password)";
// Add your variables to the submit form
loginForm.loginname.value = username;
loginForm.password.value = hex_md5(password.toLowerCase());
loginForm.encPassword.value = 'Y'
// submit the form
loginForm.submit();
```

That will bypass the form that is displayed to the user all together.

Hope that helps.